# Responsive MaterialUI TextField?

Tags: node.js, material-ui, textfield

How to make the MaterialUI textfield's width/height adjustable every time the browser is maximised/minimized? Is there a specific module I can use to make it responsive?

Comment: Look at the Grid Component. It has breakpoints that allow you to change the size on different screen sizes

Comment: I think while working on responsiveness you don't need to deal with height of text field but width only. width can be controlled with prop "fullWidth"

Comment: moreover you may use grid with breakpoints to manage width for different devices

Answer (score 0):

Usually we only play with width in responsiveness. here is the hack how you can do it.
use grid as parent and then use **fullWidth** prop or attribute in Textfield
now the textfield width will change according to the grid width

Answer (score 0):

I recommend defining a separate style for materialui breakpoints. You can call the defined breakpoints in your style file and assign width to the textfield.

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints